# Plot an implicit equation with a complex variable in SymPy

Tags: python, plot, sympy, complex-numbers

I am trying to plot a SymPy complex number in python.

Let's say I want to plot the complex unit circle with the real part on the x-axis and the imaginary part on the y-axis. See my code:

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq
from sympy.plotting import plot_implicit

z = symbols('z')
expr = Eq(abs(z), 1)

p1 = plot_implicit(expr)
```

I am defining the unit circle through this equation: abs(z)=1.
Then I am plotting the expression using plot_implicit.
I get two vertical lines going through z=-1 and z=1 with z on the x-axis and f(z) on the y-axis.

How can I achieve a satisfactory plotting of the complex unit circle?

Comment: `z = symbols('z', complex=True)`

Comment: @gboffi, I tried that, but it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'd be nice if `plot_implicit` could work directly with one complex symbol `z`, but at present it cannot: the expectation is that the user provides an expression with two real symbols. So do that, by introducing real `x, y` and making `z` an expression with `x` and `y`.

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, I
from sympy.plotting import plot_implicit

x, y = symbols('x y', real=True)
z = x + I*y
expr = Eq(abs(z), 1)    
p1 = plot_implicit(expr)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This works great. Sadly SymPy's docs is not very strong on how to handle complex numbers, at least from what I found.